# Why can't I call a class for an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

So it looks like my javascript onclick events are only functioning with ID's but when i call the class "listButton" only the first list item (All Rewards) closes the dropdown div.

When i click on any other list item (Food Rewards, Beverage Rewards, Holiday Rewards, Classes Rewards, TBA) it does not close my dropdown div.

I'm unsure why this is so. Is there another method to complete this? I must use vanilla JS.

```js
var overlay2 = document.getElementById("overlay2");
var dropdown = document.getElementById("rewardsDropdown");
var listButton = document.querySelectorAll(".listButton");

document.getElementById("dropdownButton").onclick = function() {
  dropdown.classList.add("open");
  overlay2.classList.add("open");
};

function removeOpenRewards() {
  dropdown.classList.remove("open");
  overlay2.classList.remove("open");
};

for (i = 0; i < listButton.length; i++) {
  listButton[i].addEventListener("click", removeOpenRewards);
}

overlay2.addEventListener("click", removeOpenRewards);
document.getElementById("close").addEventListener("click", removeOpenRewards);
```

```css
#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #overlay2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #overlay2.open {
  display: block;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #dropdownButtonCont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 59px;
  margin: 15px 0 20px 0;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #dropdownButtonCont button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #696969;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #dropdownButtonCont button:focus {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #dropdownButtonCont button:after {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  color: #C7C7C7;
  position: absolute;
  right: 40px;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #dropdownButtonCont button span {
  color: #EDAFBD;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown.open {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown #close {
  color: #D63A5E;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: -45px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  padding: 5px 5px 7px 6px;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown #close:hover {
  background-color: #D63A5E;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown #close:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #AF2B49;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown h4 {
  color: #505050;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown #dropdownList {
  height: 360px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 95%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown #dropdownList::-webkit-scrollbar {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown #dropdownList::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown #dropdownList>div {
  width: 95%;
  height: 59px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown #dropdownList>div button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #696969;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown #dropdownList>div button:focus {
  background-color: #D63A5E;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#container #activeRewards #mobileDropdown #rewardsDropdown #dropdownList>div button span {
  color: #EDAFBD;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="activeRewards">
    <div id="mobileDropdown">
      <div id="dropdownButtonCont">
        <button id="dropdownButton">All Rewards
          <span>(5)</span>
        </button>
      </div>

      <div id="overlay2"></div>

      <div id="rewardsDropdown">
        <span id="close">&times;</span>

        <h4>Reward Categories</h4>

        <div id="dropdownList">
          <div>
            <button class="listButton">All Rewards
              <span>(5)</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div>
            <button class="listButton">Food Rewards
              <span>(5)</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div>
            <button class="listButton">Beverage Rewards
              <span>(5)</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div>
            <button class="listButton">Holiday Rewards
              <span>(5)</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div>
            <button class="listButton">Classes Rewards
              <span>(5)</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div>
            <button class="listButton">TBA
              <span>(5)</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Look into the difference between [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)...

Comment: `document.querySelector(".listButton").addEventListener("click", removeOpenRewards);` this will add the event listener to the FIRST such element

Comment: try adding () to the end of your functions so 
`document.querySelector(".listButton").addEventListener("click", removeOpenRewards())`;

Answer (score 1):

> The Document method querySelector() returns the first Element within
>   the document that matches the specified selector, or group of
>   selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

So replace:

```
document.querySelector(".listButton").addEventListener("click", removeOpenRewards);
```

with:

```
var listButtons= document.querySelectorAll(".listbutton");

listButtons.forEach(function(listButton) {
  listButton.addEventListener("click", removeOpenRewards);
});
```

Comment: thank you for your help. i have found the solution and the edited version is working. thanks!

Comment: For maximum compatibility, you may also take the nodelist returned from querySelectorAll and slice it into an array using Array.prototype.slice.call(nodelist) prior to using forEach(). Though I feel like most browsers are better than this now.